# Can't update ubuntu - not enough free disk space

Tags: ubuntu

I know that are many questions like this. But my problem is specify. I have removed old unused kernels, also cleared system by Ubuntu-tweak. But I still don't have enough space for update.

```
/dev/sda5       116M   43M   64M  41% /boot
```

As you can see I have only 64mb free, but to update I need 72mb.

I also add output from dpkg

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii linux-image-3.13.0-77-generic        3.13.0-77.121 amd64  Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-image-extra-3.13.0-77-generic  3.13.0-77.121 amd64  Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.77.83  amd64  Generic Linux kernel image
```

And:

```
uname -r
3.13.0-77-generic
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Provide the output of du -ck /boot to see what's using all your space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Gparted` Install it from `Ubuntu Store` ?

What can it do, is that you can scale the size - storage capacity.

Try to visit this [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd) for partitioning

[image: pic]

Boot either a Ubuntu or GParted Live CD.

1. Open GParted.
2. Right-click on the main Windows Partition (If you have installed Windows).
3. Select Resize.
4. Shrink or Delete the main Windows Partition (make sure you leave at least   a couple of GB for Windows to play with, unless you're deleting it completely).
5. Click Apply (tick at the right of the icons along the top, this might take  a while, and you can't undo or stop it half-way through).
6. Right-click on your Ubuntu Partition.
7. Expand into all the free space.
8. Click Apply again.

Answer (score -1):

Consider resizing your partitions. This can be done with one of the available system rescue CD's or USB-sticks. One of them can be found [here](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage).